# Add address requirement on PayPal Donate button

Tags: paypal

I am looking to add a Donate button to my website, however the address of the person who donated must be a required field. Looking through the documentation there is the option to pass through extra button variables based on this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/)

It seems like the `address_override` parameter is the only variable that applies. Even then adding this does not make the address a required field.

[image: PayPal donation button screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address_override` is for something else (when you are passing an address you already collected) and so not applicable to what you are asking.

What you are asking is not permitted for the donation flow. The variable that controls behavior is `no_shipping`, and it can be set to `0` (default to collecting or allow sharing an address), `1` (no shipping address), and `2` (require an address).  However, for the donation flow, it is not permitted to require an address, and `no_shipping=2` will be interpreted the same as `no_shipping=0`.

So, if you absolutely must require an address, you would need to use the Buy Now flow and leave the amount of the Buy Now item blank.  On your website, you could change the button to a "Donate" image, and the item name could read "Donation to cause xyz".  But the flow on PayPal.com would be the Buy Now flow, and there would be no friendly checkbox to make it a recurring donation.

Comment: I figured as much! Thank you so much for your answer! Very helpful.